# Get activecollab api token from "trial" account, connect with postman

Tags: activecollab

I'm trying to connect to ActiveCollab API trial account with Postman.
I'm stuck at the beginning, because I can't get the required token.

I tried unsuccessfully (got an error) to run the below command in CMD and Powershell:

```
curl -XPOST -d 'email=mymail@gmail.com&password=myPassword' https://activecollab.com/api/v1/external/login
Error: 
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' for more information
'password' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

then I tried to make the call with postman GET and POST method

`url: https://activecollab.com/api/v1/external/login?email=mymail@gmail.com&password=myPassword`

with and without parameters, with basic authentication, no authentication  and APIkey authentication.....

Also tryed with https://app.activecollab.com/205491/issue-token 
with body type json: 
{
    "username": "mymail@gmail.com",
    "password": "maypassword",
}
and with username and password in headers, with no success

Can anybody make or describe how to make a postman call to get the token and an simple example how to get/add project.
Does anybody know if this [documentation](https://legacy.activecollab.com/help-classic/books/api/) is up to date?

Answer (score 0):

It's described at this page:

https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/v1/authentication.html

Your correct endpoint would be: `https://app.activecollab.com/205491/api/v1/issue-token`

Comment: That page does not describe how to get the token.

This answer gives the most information, you've got to make a POST API request to "https://activecollab.com/api/v1/external/login" first with your email and password as JSON, get the user 'intent', then post it to https://app.activecollab.com/xxxxx/api/v1/issue-token-intent with the intent, a client_name and client_vendor. Then you'll get a token back. I'm not clear on what to do with that token.


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664042/active-collab-v5-issue-token-api-call-returns-invalid-password-even-though-pas/34685298#34685298