# ActiveCollab: command line curl external login returns nothing

Tags: activecollab

I am working through the curl on the command line to try to access the API key for my account of ActiveCollab. I confused at how I might be doing that, because I have tried:

```
curl -XPOST -d 'email=user@example.com"&"password=******' https://activecollab.com/api/v1/external/login
```

This runs but doesn't return with any output, I wonder what I am supposed to do since I was trying to follow the procedure from the solution of this StackOverflow question:
[Active Collab v5 issue-token API call returns “invalid password” even though password is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664042/active-collab-v5-issue-token-api-call-returns-invalid-password-even-though-pas/34685298#34685298)

Answer (score 0):

you have syntax error when sending post request via curl.

```
curl -XPOST -d 'email=your-email@test.com&password=**********' https://activecollab.com/api/v1/external/login | python -m json.tool
```

Here's a gist that will help you with getting a token: https://gist.github.com/Elvis339/c66104950d0a7801ef544869786d2c77
Node SDK: https://github.com/Elvis339/activecollab-node-sdk
PHP SDK: https://github.com/activecollab/activecollab-feather-sdk