# ActiveCollab integration options (adding clients to projects, SMS to note etc)

Tags: api, activecollab

Is it possible to create a new project + client and assign them to the project via the API?

Also is it possible to post notes via the API? We have an SMS system that we would like to attach to projects.

Lastly, is it possible to notify one of our own inhouse systems when a task is marked complete? Perhaps using webhooks?

Thanks

Leon

Answer (score 0):

This has several questions, so lets go one by one:

First, you'll need to issue an API token. Here's how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34685298/338473

Projects and clients can be created. For examle, you can create a project, and then invite members to them:

1. https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/v1/projects/access-permissions.html
2. https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/v1/people/users/invite.html

Or add existing people to new projects (example under first link).

Notes API is also available. Here are the examples: https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/v1/projects/elements/notes/notes.html

Webhooks are supported. Open the docs here: https://activecollab.com/help/books/my-active-collab/add-ons and scroll to Webhooks section (close to the end of the document).